# "Run-time error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" when running VBA code in EXCEL for a second time (get ACCESS table)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a macro in VBA EXCEL which opens an access file and runs 4 queries, closes the access file and finally load a table from ACCESS into EXCEL.
My problem is, when I run it the second time, I get the run-time error '462'.
I read that it has something to do with the variable, that I would need to fully qualify the variables. Can you please suggest me how I have to allocate my variables?

```
    Sub open_Access()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set xcess = New Access.Application

    xcess.Visible = True

    folderpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    objectname2 = folderpath & "\"
    fileName = "Merge17.accdb"
    objectname = objectname2 & fileName

    xcess.OpenCurrentDatabase (objectname)

    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='FinalTable' And Type In (1,4,6)")) Then
         'Table Exists

         DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "FinalTable"

    Else

     'Table not exists
     End If

    xcess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "start1a"
    xcess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "start1b"
    xcess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "start2"
    xcess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "start3"

    xcess.Quit

    Dim TextFileConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim TextFileData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim TextFileField As ADODB.Field

    Set TextFileConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set TextFileData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    TextFileConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & objectname

    TextFileConn.Open

    With TextFileData
    .ActiveConnection = TextFileConn
    .Source = "FinalTable"
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open

    End With

    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA from ACCESS"

    For Each TextFileField In TextFileData.Fields
        ActiveCell.Value = TextFileField.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next TextFileField

    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset TextFileData
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    TextFileData.Close
    TextFileConn.Close

    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox ("Loading Data Complete! Time elasped: " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds")

    End Sub
```

So how do I have to change my variables?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value` is an undefined cell (happens to be any cell that you accidentally click while the macro is running)  .... `workbooks("myFile.xlsm").worksheets("Sheet1").range("a1").value` .... there is no mistake about which cell this refers to   .... if working with only one workbook, then it is ok to leave out the workbook reference

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't solve it. The error pops up at line15:
If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='FinalTable' And Type In (1,4,6)")) Then

Comment: i think that you need to tell the code that you are referring to access   .....  `If Not xcess.IsNull(xcess.DLookup("Name" ....`

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I just found that I don't need the if statement so it is working without and there is no such problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try changing the `"Name='` in the criteria argument of the DLookup to `"[Name]='` instead. The compiler might be thinking that `Name` is the undefined variable and not the reference variable from the domain.

I say this because I have similar code but for the `DCount` function: `If DCount("PropertyID", "tbl_Properties", "[PropertyID] Like '*" & IDSearch & "*'") <> 0 Then` And also the examples from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172176(v=office.11).aspx) show similar code.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I just found that I don't need the if statement so it is working without and there is no such problem anymore.